# How do I add extra functions to a mock and have it pass typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have a mock for `@react-native-community/netinfo` but I want to expand it so that I have an extra function that I can call to update the mock data.  e.g. `setConnectionState` but if I do the following

```
import NetInfo, {
  NetInfoState,
  NetInfoStateType,
  setConnectionState,
} from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
```

it fails typescript.

How would I code it so that the mock will allow additional functionality that is not present in the original type?

[The mock](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/dbcfbc1be7e75d2cc09c8dce08fd976c07874d03/packages/auth-context/src/__mocks__/@react-native-community/netinfo.ts)

[The test](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/dbcfbc1be7e75d2cc09c8dce08fd976c07874d03/packages/auth-context/src/__tests__/netinfoMock.test.tsx)

I know I can add the following to make it pass TypeScript but I want the scope of usage to only be on Jest

```
declare module '@react-native-community/netinfo' {
  export function resetConnectionState(): void;
  export function setConnectionState(next: NetInfoState): void;
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that a mock adding/changing api of a package is a bit of a smell tbh. Somewhat opinionated, but maybe moving it outside, and let both the mock and the test depend on it, is a better alternative - at least, it makes it clear what is part of the interface of the package and what is an implementation details for the mock

Comment: I would want to, but that would mean I would have to change the netinfo source do so.